# Quiero que un campo me muestre el resultado de una resta de fecha, fecha actual menos fecha de inicio en javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

Tengo este código que implementé en un pdf con adobe Acrobat:

```
var A = this.getField("fecha_ingreso_af_date").value; var B = new Date().value;

var C = B.getTime() - A.getTime();

this.getField("antiguedad") = value.C;
```

Es un formulario donde "fecha_de_ingreso_af_date" es un campo fecha y "antiguedad" es otro campo donde se deben mostrar los años trabajados de la resta de la fecha actual a la ingresada en el campo fecha.

Comment: Prueba: (1) Cambiar `var B = new Date().value` por `var B = new Date();` y (2) cambiar `this.getField("antiguedad") = value.C;` por `this.getField("antiguedad").value = C;`